# How to iterate over the sets in a SetMultimap without a cast?

Tags: java, guava

I have a `SetMultimap<X> x` and I need to do something with each `Set<X>` this map contains (I don't need the keys at this point).
I can call `x.asMap().values()`, but unfortunately this method returns a `Collection<Collection<X>>`. So when iterating through this I need to cast every `Collection<X>` into a `Set<X>`:

```
SetMultimap<X> x;
for (Collection<X> y : x.asMap().values()) {
  foo((Set<X>)y); // foo only takes a Set<X>
}
```

Is there another without this cast? Of course the documentation of `SetMultimap` states that this cast is safe, but it would be nicer if the cast wouldn't be needed at all. The same problem occurs with a `SortedSetMultimap`.

Comment: BTW, the reason it's like this: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/issues/detail?id=118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) There is no reason you should need a `Set`. `Set` has no methods beyond those specified by `Collection`. The collections you get are sets, but the variable types are not. Use the Collections, there is no need for casting.

b) if you do need the `Set`, or the `SortedSet` in case of a `SortedSetMultimap`, you have to iterate over the keys:

```
SetMultimap<String,Integer> mmap = Multimaps.newSetMultimap(map, supplier);
for(String key : mmap.keySet()){
    Set<Integer> set = mmap.get(key);
}
```

or

```
SortedSetMultimap<String,Integer> mmap = 
    Multimaps.newSortedSetMultimap(map, supplier);
for(String key : mmap.keySet()){
    SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = mmap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: You are right with the Set interface, but I have the same problem with SortedSet, too. So I'll probably go with iterating over the keys.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a better solution, but is not that efficient (but without cast).

```
for (K k : x.keySet()) {
    Set<X> a = x.get(k);
}
```